# Hibernate pooled vs pooled-lo id generator

Tags: hibernate, hilo

This article (https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) gives a good explanation on the differences for the `hilo`, `pooled` and `pooled-lo` optimizers for sequence generators. It also explains that since hibernate 5, `pooled` optimizer is used as the default if the allocation size is greater than 1.

Is there an advantage in using the `pooled-lo` optimizer vs the default `pooled` optimizer? I did notice that for `pooled`, there is one extra database call to get the "next hi" value (I think because of how the computation works). Other than that, I'm not sure if there's a difference in performance between the two.

Why is `pooled` used as the default? And is there a significant advantage in using `pooled-lo`?